# Publish one of several modules as a library using SBT

Tags: sbt

I have a program that divides nicely into two modules, the business logic (BL) and the command line interface (CLI).

I'd like to publish BL as a library so it can also be used in a web app, both on the server (JVM) and the browser (ScalaJS).

Is it possible to publish just the BL module using SBT?  If so, how?

I know how to put BL into its own project and publish the entire project as a library.  I could then suck that into the original program with the CLI as well as the web app.  But it seems easier to maintain if the BL and CLI could simply live as two modules in the same project and publish the one that I need elsewhere.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know how to [publish the project](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Publishing.html) and you also know how to setup [multi projects](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html), the next step is to setup the corresponding settings for publishing the module and run the task from that one.

your `build.sbt` should be like

```
ThisBuild / organization := "org"
ThisBuild / version      := "version"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "scalaVersion"

lazy val bl = (project in file("bl"))
  .settings(
    // settings for bl
  )

lazy val cli = (project in file("cli"))
  .settings(
    // settings for cli
  )
```

and then you can run a task from a subproject doing `subproject/task`. Based on the previous `build.sbt` file, the command to run the task should be like

```
> sbt bl/publish
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @Gastón!  Now I just need to debug my publishing stuff.  Today publishing a library started asking for a password instead of using SSH.  If I publish locally, it goes to Ivy's cache rather than Coursier's cache.  Not just this one; other library projects that used to work, too.